# constexpr bug in clang but not in gcc?

Tags: c++, clang, constexpr, c++14

Let's take this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {
    constexpr int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
      // code
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return foo::main(argc, argv);
}
```

Depend on what **code** is, clang will complain or no. If code is:

```
cout << "Hello!";
return 0;
```

clang complains:

> error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression
>   [-Winvalid-constexpr]
>
> ```
> constexpr int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
> ```
>
> note: non-constexpr function 'operator<< >'
>   cannot be used in a constant expression
>
> ```
>     std::cout << "Hello!";
> ```
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/ostream:530:5:
>   note: declared here
>
> ```
> operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
> ```

Fair enough, constexpr functions can't contain any cout statements, as we know. But what happens if we do this?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    std::cout << argv[i];
```

clang allows it! OK, but this can't possibly be a constexpr function even though it is marked constexpr, let's try to use it in constexpr context.

```
int arr[foo::main(argc, argv)];
```

It works! So it must be clang bug? Reason I say clang because gcc complains:

> error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr int foo::main(int,
>   char**)' not a return-statement

So my conclusion is clang is wrong and gcc is right.

Comment: Produces "statement not allowed in constexpr function" on clang 3.4.

Comment: What version of clang are you using?

Comment: I am using clang 3.5 `std=c++1y`

Comment: I didn't even think clang allowed constexpr in general

Comment: @ToryWebster So why are you tagging this `c++11`? The answer to your question depends on it.

Comment: @Gmercer015, Clang has been C++11-complete for a while now and more recently, C++14-complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compile your code in C++1y mode which contains wording to relax `constexpr` restrictions including all looping statements.

Have a look at [N3652](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3652.html) which introduced these changes.

Comment: Where is the specific place that allows it to use `operator<<` on `cout`?

Comment: @Griwes I ignored the body of the for-loop, because I thought that OP is specifically wondering about the loop. But yes, that is odd.

Answer (score 13):

***Clang is correct here.***

**First example**

Here, the code is:

```
constexpr int foo::main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::cout << argv[i];
  return 0;
}
```

*In C++11*, this code is ill-formed, because the body contains an *expression-statement*, which is not permitted in a `constexpr` function definition.

*In C++1y*, this code is ill-formed with no diagnostic required, because a call to `foo::main` can never produce a constant expression (because it always calls `operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)`, which is not `constexpr`).

**Second example**

In this case, the code is:

```
constexpr int foo::main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    std::cout << argv[i];
  return 0;
}
```

*In C++11*, this code is ill-formed, because it contains a `for`-statement.

*In C++1y*, this code is valid. In particular, `foo::main(0, 0)` is a constant expression (with value `0`). Since `foo::main` is usable in a constant expression, Clang is not permitted to reject it, and does not do so.

**Third example**

```
int arr[foo::main(argc, argv)];
```

The array bound here is *not* a constant expression (because it reads `argc` and `argv`, which are not constant). However, Clang supports variable-length arrays as an extension by default. You can specify `-pedantic-errors` to put clang into strictly-conforming mode, and in that mode it will reject this code.

**GCC's diagnostic:**

> error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr int foo::main(int, char**)' not a return-statement

is incorrect in both C++11 and C++1y. In C++11, it's incorrect because the rule is more subtle (the body of a `constexpr` function can contain `typedef`s and a few other constructs, not just `return`-statements). In C++1y, the rule no longer exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

So gcc 4.8.1 does not implement relaxed constexpr restraints, but clang 3.5 does. My mistake was that clang and gcc both have variable length array extensions. if I had used std::array instead, both compilers would reject the code. What I still don't understand is if clang allows relaxed constexpr, then why is it not a constexpr?

Comment: Because `operator<<` is not constexpr.

Comment: I suggest compiling with at least `-pedantic` to avoid this.